# Finding common / disjoint lines between two files, including lines in file B that start with lines from file A

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm trying to compare two files in a way that's tolerant of lines in the second file that *start with* lines in the first file (but have unwanted garbage appended).

Consider the following code:

```
printf '%s\n' 5234 2234 3234 4234 1234 >NumsOnFile.txt
printf '%s\n' 423499 1234 223401 3234 >UserNums.txt
```

I want to generate two output files: `good.txt` with the numbers found in both files (even just as a substring), and `bad.txt` with numbers that existed in `UserNums.txt` but not in `NumsOnFile.txt`.

---

### Existing Implementation Attempt

#### Stage 1: Eliminating already-correct lines

I'm currently doing this in two stages. My current attempt at the first stage looks like the following:

```
sort -n UserNums.txt > a 
sort -n NumsOnFile.txt > b
awk '!a[$0]++' a > A
awk '!a[$0]++' b > B
comm -23 A B > bad.txt  
comm -12 A B > good.txt
```

I expect `good.txt` to contain the following:

```
1234
3234
```

...and `bad.txt` to contain the following:

```
423499
223401
```

#### Stage 2: Trying to look for substrings

Then, I'm processing `bad.txt`, looking at whether any matches are found after the last character of each line is removed:

```
read file
if [ -s bad.txt ]
   then 
    sed 's/.$//' bad.txt > checker.txt # removes last character from each line
    sort -n checker.txt > X
    comm -23 X B > checker.txt 
    comm -12 X B >> good.txt
    cat checker.txt > bad.txt 
else
    echo "File is empty"
fi
```

After this second stage, `good.txt` should now have all the numbers that match both files (even if they were only a substring in UserNums.txt):

```
1234
2234
3234
4234
```

...whereas `bad.txt` should have the original numbers that didn't match:

```
423499
223401
```

---

### What's Wrong Here?

I think my logic is sound, but not using the correct commands or the commands used incorrectly. But the `if` may be getting caught up on something.

- The bad.txt and good.txt files are not being populated with desired data. Numbers from both files are ending up in both or some numbers are missing all together.
- good.txt ends up empty even though I have manually searched for two 
  matching numbers.

Comment: tl;dr -- too wordy; please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `comm` requires input to be sorted according to LC_COLLATE. This means that you generally can't use `sort -n`.

Comment: Sorry, but definitively not understanding what you want. Please include an example of A and B. Also, wouldn't be the line that match in the good.txt and the line that doesn't in bad.txt ?

Comment: Thanks all! @AndreGelinas, do my examples help at all, they are a bit small scale in comparison to the real files.

Comment: @glenn , less words more examples better than my short essay before ?

Comment: That's a lot of temporary files. Please show the original input files, UserNums.txt and NumsOnFile.txt, and show the output files you want. I suspect this can be done with a single awk program, but it's still not clear.

Comment: UserNums.txt is an unsorted version of file __B__ and NumsOnFile.txt is an unsorted version of __A__.  The desired output would be what the __ex.__ of Good.txt look like.

Comment: Remove the `-n` argument to `sort` and then `comm` will work (as that other guy told you hours ago). Granted, your values will no longer be numerically sorted, but you can do that in postprocessing.

Comment: Just to be clear, though -- you want `4234` to be in `good.txt`, even though it **wasn't** found in UserNums.txt (which only contained `432499`)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I was unsure how to explain, but many of the account nums have account designators attached to them, I only need the base account num which is found in NumsOnFile.txt The `if` loop uses `sed` to remove the last characters each run through the loop.

Comment: Are your account IDs all the same length in the real dataset (as they are in your sample data here), so you could just eliminate the garbage by truncating at a fixed number of bytes per line?

Comment: I've tried to edit the question to be a bit more clear (it originally almost looked like two completely different questions, as opposed to two stages of the same operation). That said, there's still room to simplify it: There's no point to include content about operations that *work*, as opposed to operations that don't.

Comment: BTW, which version of bash are you targeting? Can we assume 4.1 or newer?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy omg thanks your edit to my question is great!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am unsure if it matters I am running an HP-UX system using ksh88

Comment: ...then why is this tagged `linux`? Folks generally make a bunch of assumptions with that tag (like use of GNU tools) that don't apply to the UNIX family more generally. And it should certainly be tagged `ksh` rather than just `shell` if that's what you want answers to target.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I still have a lot to learn about linux and UNIX environments, thank you for the info! Changed the tags,

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, while I have ksh93 handy (and could modify my answer to target that shell pretty easily), ksh88 is trickier - I don't have a copy on hand to test against, and there's a much bigger difference in terms of available features.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well that is unfortunate, I appreciate all the help, I will keep testing and researching with this newly gathered info

Comment: ...so, if you *wanted* something written with the same logic that was in my answer, it would probably be easiest to write in pure awk, rather than in ksh88 (or as an awk/shell hybrid script, when is often worst-of-both-worlds in terms of performance). Also, quite a lot faster to run -- a good awk implementation is typically ~10x faster than ksh93, and ksh93 is one of the fastest shells out there.

Comment: I did a test with my answer on pksh, using the proper shebang, which is basically ksh88 (sorry that's the closer I can get with ksh88 on HP-UX :) )...and it was working directly without correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can make output with these commands

```
cat NumsOnFile.txt UserNums.txt | cut -c1-4 |sort | uniq -d > good.txt
grep -vFxf NumsOnFile.txt UserNums.txt > bad.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then maybe that should do the trick

```
#!/bin/bash

# All files are assumed to be in the same directory. Please modify the paths if necessary.

# Opening files for writing

exec 3>./Bad.txt
exec 4>./Good.txt
exec 5>./correction.sed

#Creating an array for the account numbers.
while read line; do
    accountNumber[$line]=$line
done < ./NumsOnFile.txt

# Comparing the user's file with your account file
while read line; do
    # That takes only the first 4 characters. If your account number are of a different length please modify
    accUser=${line:0:4}
    if [[ ${accountNumber[$accUser]} -ne $line ]]; then
        #if different then write the bad file and the script to correct the original file
        echo $line >&3
        echo "s|$line|$accUser|g" >&5
    else
        #if same, just write the good file
        echo $line >&4
    fi
done < ./UserNums.txt

# Closing files

exec 3>&-
exec 4>&-
exec 5>&-

# Executing sed script to correct the input file

sed -i.bck --file=./correction.sed ./UserNums.txt
```

Hope it could help.

## Edit

Edited to take Charles' comments into account

Comment: It would be much more efficient if you opened your output files up top: `exec 3>Bad.txt 4>Good.txt` up at the front of the file, and then you can `echo "$line" >&3` or `echo "$line" >&4` without having it re-open the file just for one line of output.

Comment: As for rewriting `UsersNums.txt` over and over -- much more efficient to, say, just retain an associative array with your numbers as keys, and `unset` each one when you want to remove it; when you've completed all the processing, you can rewrite the file just once.

Comment: @andregelinas with `accUser=${:0:X}` I could only get account nums with the length of `X`? I did not give a great example as not all account numbers are even length.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So I should save my lines into an array as Andre shows, and after all the comparisons are made save to a file?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed. Or open another file to create a .sed script and execute it at the end.

Comment: @Flunkie Yes, that's what it does : accUser=${[VariableName]:[start position];[length]}. Start position 0 is the first character.